# directory Search using a background worker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, directorysearcher

In my application, I have option to search a directory. If the user searching local drive then I'm searching the catalog first (searching the Index), then the directories

`DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories("*" + AsearchString + "*",System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)`.

In case of network searching (network folders), I am doing only directory search. Now the problem is, the user may or may not have access permission for files or folders. I am getting unauthorized exception and background worker stops right there, my confusion is how I can catch the exception (in case of `PathTooLong` or `unauthorized` exception, this happens when I am searching network drives  ) so if there is an exception just log or omit it and continue working.

I am putting my work around below, I don't know why `try/catch` not working, or where I should move it so in case of exception it will disregard and keep going. I had to put the lots of code below, apologies for that, I appreciate any suggestions.

**UPDATE**: 
Ignoring the exception in do work will stop the bcw, so I figured out my exception handling was incorrect. I have updated my code.

```
private void bwSearch_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Argument != null && e.Argument.GetType() == typeof(List<string>))
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor));
        }
        else 
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        }
        listViewBWSearchStatus = true;
        List<string> par = e.Argument as List<string>;
        string path = par[0];
        string searchString = par[1];

        try
        {
            if (FileSystemHelper.PathIsNetworkPath(path))
            {
                DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                foreach (FileInfo fi in dInfo.GetFiles("*" + searchString + "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    if (bwSearch.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        if (this.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.Cursor = Cursors.Default));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    bwSearch.ReportProgress(0, fi);
                }
                foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dInfo.GetDirectories("*" + searchString + "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    if (bwSearch.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    bwSearch.ReportProgress(0, d);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=""Application=Windows""");
                string searchDirectoryFormated = path.Replace(@"\", @"/");

                // Folder name search (case insensitive), does not search sub directories
                var directorySearchQuery = @"SELECT System.ItemName,System.ItemPathDisplay FROM SystemIndex " +
                @"WHERE directory = 'file:" + searchDirectoryFormated + "' AND System.ItemType = 'Directory' AND System.Itemname LIKE '%" + searchString + "%' ";

                // File name search (case insensitive), does not search sub directories
                var fileSearchQuery = @"SELECT System.ItemName,System.ItemPathDisplay FROM SystemIndex " +
                            @"WHERE directory = 'file:" + searchDirectoryFormated + "' AND System.ItemName LIKE '%" + searchString + "%' ";

                connection.Open();

                var command = new OleDbCommand(directorySearchQuery, connection);
                Dictionary<string, string> directoryResult = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                using (var r = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (r.Read())
                    {
                        if (bwSearch.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (!directoryResult.ContainsKey(r.GetString(1)))
                        {
                            directoryResult.Add(r.GetString(1), r.GetString(0));
                            DirectoryInfo dirInfoIndexed = new DirectoryInfo(r.GetString(1));
                            bwSearch.ReportProgress(0, dirInfoIndexed);
                        }
                    }
                }

                command = new OleDbCommand(fileSearchQuery, connection);
                Dictionary<string, string> fileResult = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                using (var r = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (r.Read())
                    {
                        if (bwSearch.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (!fileResult.ContainsKey(r.GetString(1)))
                        {
                            fileResult.Add(r.GetString(1), r.GetString(0));
                            FileInfo fileInfoIndexed = new FileInfo(r.GetString(1));
                            bwSearch.ReportProgress(0, fileInfoIndexed);
                        }
                    }
                }


                connection.Close();

                DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

                foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dInfo.GetDirectories("*" + searchString + "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    if (bwSearch.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    bwSearch.ReportProgress(0, d);
                }

                foreach (FileInfo fi in dInfo.GetFiles("*" + searchString + "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    if (bwSearch.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    bwSearch.ReportProgress(0, fi);
                }
            }
        }
        //catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { } // ignoring the exception will stop the background worker
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { throw;}
        catch (System.Exception )
        {
            throw;// new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

private void bwSearch_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.UserState != null && e.UserState.GetType() == typeof(FileInfo))
    {

        FileInfo fInfo = e.UserState as FileInfo;
        ListViewItem[] searchInfo = this.listView.Items.Find(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fInfo.Name), false);
        if (searchInfo == null || searchInfo.Count() == 0)
        {
            string fileFullName = fInfo.FullName;
            string lastAccessTime = fInfo.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString();
            string imageKey = "";
            if (this.listView.SmallImageList.Images.ContainsKey(fInfo.Extension.ToLower()))
                imageKey = fInfo.Extension.ToLower();
            else
                imageKey = Explorer._Unknown;
            string strFileType = Explorer._Unknown;
            fileExtensionToFileType.TryGetValue(fInfo.Extension.ToString(), out strFileType);
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strFileType))
                strFileType = Explorer._Unknown;
            ListViewItem itemL = new ListViewItem(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fInfo.Name), imageKey);
            itemL.Name = fInfo.Name;
            itemL.Tag = fInfo;
            ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] subItem = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
            {
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itemL, lastAccessTime),
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itemL, strFileType),
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itemL, Explorer.SizeSuffix(fInfo.Length)),
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itemL, fileFullName)
            };
            itemL.SubItems.AddRange(subItem);
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                this.listView.BeginUpdate();
                this.listView.Items.Add(itemL);
                this.listView.EndUpdate();
            }));
        }
    }
    else if (e.UserState != null && e.UserState.GetType() == typeof(DirectoryInfo))
    {

        DirectoryInfo dInfo = e.UserState as DirectoryInfo;
        string fullName = dInfo.FullName;
        ListViewItem[] searchDirectories = this.listView.Items.Find(dInfo.Name, false);
        if (searchDirectories == null || searchDirectories.Count() == 0)
        {
            ListViewItem itemL = new ListViewItem(dInfo.Name, Strings.FolderOpen);
            itemL.Name = dInfo.Name;
            itemL.Tag = dInfo;
            ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] subItem = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
            {
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itemL, dInfo.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString()),
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itemL, "File folder"),
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itemL, ""),
                new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(itemL, fullName)
            };
            itemL.SubItems.AddRange(subItem);
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                this.listView.BeginUpdate();
                this.listView.Items.Add(itemL);
                this.listView.EndUpdate();
            }));
        }
    }
}

private void bwSearch_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        if (e.Error.GetType() == typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException))
        {
        }
        if (e.Error.GetType() == typeof(Exception))
        { }
    }
    if (e.Error == null && e.Cancelled == false)
    {
        _ResetEventSearch.Set();
        listViewBWSearchStatus = false;
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.Cursor = Cursors.Default));
        }
        else
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** :

This part of the code searches for files or folders based on the user defined string. I didn't want to stall users thread since searching will be a pile load of work, so I introduced background worker instead. I got exception when I was trying to read directories in `foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dInfo.GetDirectories("*" + searchString + "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))`. I think, when It was trying to get directory info or file info, it got stuck since user didn't had access permission.

Initially I wasn't throwing exception, hence, after getting the exception the bcw didn't move further. Instead it reported error and raised run worker completed event. After I have added `throw` bcw continued working for the rest of the directories.

Comment: Did you know, you can use the local search index to search remote folders.

Comment: I saw [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231257(v=vs.85).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on msdn, I wanted to work around but later it went out of scope.  We can do something like this ' SELECT System.ItemName FROM zarasmachine.SystemIndex WHERE SCOPE='file://zarasmachine/C:/Files/Reports' '. If it is not too much can you please give an example @scott.

Comment: You wont catch any of those exceptions in the handler for `ProgressChanged`. Focus on the `DoWork` event handler.

Comment: @S.Rojak you are correct, ignoring exception will not work. It has to throw the exception. I'm updating my code.

Comment: The BW stops because you rethrow the exception using `throw`. The BW stops if you remove `throw`, because you're not inside a loop at that point, and so the `bwSearch_DoWork()` method returns (ending the work). If you want to continue, you need to put the try/catch _inside_ your loop, around the specific operations that could throw an exception, so that the loop in your BW can continue to run. Unfortunately, it's not clear from your post what it is you want your program to continue doing if an exception is thrown. But hopefully there's enough information here to get you back on track.